# How to input float values in a n-tuple matrix using python?

Tags: python, math, matrix, tuples

Pardon if my question is too basic since I've just started learning python

```
rows = int(input("Enter the Number of rows : "))   
column = int(input("Enter the Number of Columns: "))

print("Enter the elements of Matrix:")
matrix_a = [[tuple(input()) for i in range(column)] for i in range(rows)]
print("First Matrix is: ")
for n in matrix_a:
   print(n)
```

Getting the output as

```
Enter the Number of rows : 
2
Enter the Number of Columns: 
2
Enter the elements of Matrix:
123
456
987
644
First Matrix is: 
[('1', '2', '3'), ('4', '5', '6')]
[('9', '8', '7'), ('6', '4', '4')]
```

How can I input float values as elements of this n-tuple matrix.

like [ (0.9, 0.6, 0.5), (0.4, 0.5, 0.1) ]

Comment: What do you mean?? just get a float value as input

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to input float values, you need to define a delimiter, e.g. a space between the input values. This also enables you to enter multi-digit numbers, which is not possible in the original version.

```
...
matrix_a = [[tuple(map(float, input().split(" ")))
             for i in range(column)] for i in range(rows)]

...

Enter the Number of rows : 2
Enter the Number of Columns: 2
Enter the elements of Matrix:
1.2 3.2 1.4
1 2 3
123
1.3 12 1
First Matrix is: 
[(1.2, 3.2, 1.4), (1.0, 2.0, 3.0)]
[(123.0,), (1.3, 12.0, 1.0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(,)` Python tuple creator to avoid splitting input elements:

```
rows = int(input("Enter the Number of rows : "))   
column = int(input("Enter the Number of Columns: "))

print("Enter the elements of Matrix:")
matrix_a = [[(input(),) for i in range(column)] for i in range(rows)]
print("First Matrix is: ")
for n in matrix_a:
   print(n)
```

**Output:**

```
Enter the Number of rows : 1
Enter the Number of Columns: 1
Enter the elements of Matrix:
999
First Matrix is: 
[('999',)]
```

Also, you can use a generator if you want a tuple of float elements:

```
rows = int(input("Enter the Number of rows : "))   
column = int(input("Enter the Number of Columns: "))

print("Enter the elements of Matrix:")
matrix_a = [[tuple(float(a) for a in input()) for i in range(column)] for i in range(rows)]
print("First Matrix is: ")
for n in matrix_a:
   print(n)
```

> Enter the Number of rows : 1
> Enter the Number of Columns: 1
> Enter the elements of Matrix:
> 555
> First Matrix is:
> [(5.0, 5.0, 5.0)]